# Adding OpenSSL into existing app

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm adding SSL support (currently pushing forward with OpenSSL) to an existing application.  I've never done anything with cryptology before and after reading numerous articles and watching videos I'm still a little confused as to how I can implement it for my specific situation.

Our software is client/server, and the end-user purchases both and will install it on their premises.

My first bit of confusion is regarding certificates and private keys, and how to manage these.  Should I have one certificate that get installed along with the app?  Should each end-user have their own certificate generated?  What about private keys?  Do I bake the private key into the server binary?  Or should there be a file with the private key?

I'm sure this is a solved problem, but I'm not quite sure where to look, or what to search for.

Thanks for any help and advice.

Answer (score 5):

> Adding OpenSSL into existing app

If all you need is an example of a SSL/TLS client, have a look at the OpenSSL's wiki and [TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) example.

---

> My first bit of confusion is regarding certificates and private keys, and how to manage these.

Yes, key management and distribution is the hardest problem in crpyto.

Public CAs have legally binding documents covering these practices. They are called Certification Practice Statements (CPS). You can have a lot of fun with them because the company lawyers tell you what you don't want to hear (or the marketing department refuses to tell you).

For example, here's an excerpt from [Apple Inc. Certification Authority Certification Practice Statement](http://images.apple.com/certificateauthority/pdf/Apple_AAI_CPS_v4.0.pdf):

```
2.4.2. CA disclaimers of warranties
To the extent permitted by applicable law, Subscriber agreements,
if applicable, disclaim warranties from Apple, including any
warranty of merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.

2.4.3. CA limitations of liability
To the extent permitted by applicable law, Subscriber agreements,
if applicable, shall limit liability on the part of Apple and shall
exclude liability for indirect, special, incidental, and
consequential damages.
```

So, Apple is selling you a product with no warranty and that offers no liability!!! And they want you to trust them and give them money... what a racket! And its not just Apple - other CAs have equally obscene CPS'es.

---

> Should I have one certificate that get installed along with the app?

It depends. If you are running your own PKI (i.e., you are the CA and control the root certificate), then distribute your root X509 certificate with you application and nothing else. There's no need to trust any other CAs, like Verisign or Startcom.

If you are using someone else's PKI (or the Internet's PKI specified in RFC 5280), then  distribute only the root X509 certificate needed to validate the chain. In this case, you will distribute one CA's root X509 certificate for validation. You could potentially trust just about any certificate signed by that particular CA, however (and its likely to be in the 10's of thousands if you are not careful).

If you don't know in advance, then you have to do like browsers and pick a bunch of CAs to trust and carry around their root certificates for your application. You can grab a list of them from Mozilla, for example. You could potentially trust just about any certificate signed by all CAs, however (and its likely to be in the 10's of millions if you are not careful).

There's a lot more to using public CAs like browsers, and you should read through Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut00/pubs/book.pdf). Pay particular attention to the Security Diversification strategies.

When the client connects to your server, your server should send its X509 certificate (the leaf certificate) and any intermediate certificates required to build a valid chain back to the root certificate you distribute.

Finally, you can get free SSL/TLS certificates trusted by most major browsers (including mobile) from Eddy Nigg at [Startcom](http://www.startcom.org/). He charges for the revocation (if needed) because that's where the cost lies. Other CAs charge you up front and pocket the proceeds if not needed.

---

> Should each end-user have their own certificate generated?

That is possible, too. That's called client certificates or client authentication authentication. Ideally, you would be running your own PKI because (1) you control everything (including the CA operations) and don't need to trust anyone outside the organization; and (2) it can get expensive to have a commercial CA sign every user's certificate.

If you don't want to use client side certificates, please look into PSK (Preshared Keys) and SRP (Secure Remote Password). Both beat the snot out of classic X509 using RSA key transport. PSK and SRP do so because they provide mutual authentication and channel binding. In these systems, both the client and server know the secret or password and the channel is setup up; or one (or both) does not know and channel setup fails. The plain text username and password are never put on the wire as in RSA transport and `basic_auth` schemes. (I prefer SRP because its based on Diffie-Hellman, and have implemented it in a few systems).

---

> What about private keys?

Yes, you need to manage the private keys associated with certificates. You can (1) store them in the filesystem with permissions or ACLs; (2) store them in a Keystore or Keychain like Android, Mac OS X, iOS, or Windows; (3) store them in an Hardware Security Module (HSM); or (4) store them remotely while keeping them online using [Key Management Interop Protocol](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=kmip) (KMIP).

Note: unattended key storage on a server is a problem without a solution. See, for example, Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut00/pubs/book.pdf), page 368 under "Wicked Hard Problems" and "Problems without Solutions".

---

> Do I bake the private key into the server binary?

No. You generate them when needed and then store them with the best protection you can provide.

---

> Or should there be a file with the private key?

Yes, something like that. See above.

---

> I'm sure this is a solved problem, but I'm not quite sure where to look, or what to search for.

I'm not sure I would really call it solved because of the key distribution problem.

And some implementations are just really bad, so you would likely wonder how the code passed for production.

The first thing you probably want (since your focusing on key management) is a treatment of "key management" and "key hierarchies".

You might also want some reference material. From the security engineering point of view, read Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut00/pubs/book.pdf) and Ross Anderson's [Security Engineering](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html). From an implementation standpoint, grab a copy of [Network Security with OpenSSL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600270X) and [SSL and TLS: Designing and Building Secure Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615983).

Comment: Wow, there's some fantastic information in there.  Thanks for taking the time and typing that up.

Comment: @jww - Can you please take a look at this(http://stackoverflow.com/q/30327023/730807) and offer your valuable insights ?